como creo una carpeta que guarde todos los objetos generados por mi makefile al compilar?

Aquí está la estructura de mi proyecto en este momento, la carpeta 'constructores' es donde se guardan todos mis .o cuando se crean, pero la carpeta necesita ser creada manualmente para funcionar, quiero hacer una regla 'si no existe crearla' pero no sé cómo hacerlo porque los recursos que miré dicen que es dependiente del entorno, las primeras líneas de mi archivo makefile son CXX ?= g++ y CXXFLAGS = -Wall -g -std=c++11 ¿qué líneas necesito agregar para que la carpeta constructores se cree cuando otros desarrolladores escriben el comando 'make' en cualquier entorno? (no quiero agregar una carpeta vacía en mi repositorio), también las líneas que describo aquí funcionan para que cualquier compilador de c++ funcione con mi código?

Este es SO en Español, por favor traduce tu publicación, o dirigete a [SO]

lo siento no me percate, gracias

En cualquier sistema POSIX compliant mkdir -p debería resolverte el problema.

intente hacer esto $(BUILD_DIR):
@if not exist "$(BUILD_DIR)" mkdir "$(BUILD_DIR)", pero sale /bin/sh: -c: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make: *** [Makefile:20: constructores] Error 2 incluso cuando añado el -p dentro o fuera de las comillas

Muestra el código de tu makefile. No podemos ayudarte con algo que no vemos.

Para que la carpeta constructores se cree automáticamente cuando se ejecute make, puedes modificar tu Makefile para incluir una regla que verifique si la carpeta existe y, si no, la cree.
Así un ejemplo de cómo podrías hacerlo:
CXX ?= g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -g -std=c++11

# Definir la carpeta donde se guardarán los archivos objeto
OBJDIR = constructores

# Definir los archivos objeto (esto dependerá de tus archivos fuente)
OBJECTS = $(OBJDIR)/archivo1.o $(OBJDIR)/archivo2.o # y así sucesivamente

# Regla para compilar el programa final
programa: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o programa $(OBJECTS)

# Regla para compilar archivos .cpp a archivos .o en la carpeta OBJDIR
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cpp | $(OBJDIR)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

# Regla para crear la carpeta OBJDIR si no existe
$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)

# Limpiar los archivos generados
clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJDIR) programa

Las líneas que mencionas (CXX ?= g++ y CXXFLAGS = -Wall -g -std=c++11) deberían funcionar en cualquier entorno donde el compilador de C++ utilizado sea compatible con estas opciones. Sin embargo, es recomendable probar en los entornos que planeas soportar.
Esto sería mucho más fácil si pudiéramos ver tu Makefile.

hola, gracias por tu respuesta, los comandos me ayudaron porque no me funcionaban por el sistema operativo (windows) despues de buscar pudo funcionar windows o unix ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)   MKDIR = powershell -Command "if (!(Test-Path '$(BUILD_DIR)')) { New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path '$(BUILD_DIR)' }"   RM = cmd.exe /c "for %f in ($(BUILD_DIR)\*.o) do del %f"  RMDIR = cmd.exe /c rmdir /S /Q  REXE = cmd.exe /c "del /f pseudorandom_numbers.exe"  else  MKDIR = mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)  RM = rm -f  RMDIR = rm -rf  REXE = rm -f pseudorandom_numbers.exe endif

disculpa el formato, pero MKDIR se ejecuta para crear la carpeta y RMDIR es remove directory, REXE para el ejectuable y RM es para los objetos cuando ejecutas make clean
